# Cv2.hogdescriptor.setsvmdetector multiclass classification

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I wonder opencv-python can detect multiple classes.

Is it possible to label class like 1,2,3,4,5... other than 1 , -1??

I have more than 100 classes.

If i cannot use opencv for multiclass classification, what would be the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use OpenCV's `SVM` to do that.
Look at the [following example](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_svm/py_svm_opencv/py_svm_opencv.html#svm-opencv).

There you will see that the classes are labeled as numbers from 0 to 9.
You just have to provide a response array (containing your original class labels), which is added to the train method. OpenCV's `SVM` automatically retrieves the class labels. You can verify this by saving the trained `SVM` model - the generated file contains a list of class labels.